# Is usb relay board safe for high powers?

Tags: usb, relay

I'd like to use this usb device:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956365824.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.64552e0ezng2GS

to control 220-240V/AC appliances, drawing around 5A. Specifically, to control my central heating unit, which is not programmable itself.

The device seems easy to program and to wire, however, I am concerned because I found this warning:

"The USB specification has clearly provided guidelines as to how power should be utilized from the USB port, and surging currents produced by high-current mechanical relays is strictly prohibited."

(https://ncd.io/choosing-the-right-usb-relay-controller/#document-5)

I am wondering whether that warning applies to the device above (whose relay's specs can be found here: http://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf).

Thanks!

Comment: "220-240V/AC appliances, drawing around 5A. Specifically, to control my central heating unit" those numbers don't seem plausible - they are too low to be the actual heating/cooling power, and far too high to be control circuits.  This is not a project you should attempt until you have a far deeper understanding of what you are trying to control and the issues that implies.

Comment: It's the controller, not the actual heating power. The 5A is taken from the controller's specs, where it is reported as "contact rating". I couldn't find any other power or current specification.

Comment: So what is the actual power you are trying to switch?

Comment: are you sure that you cannot use a regular thermostat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the diagram, there is likely no isolation on the USB board (I only see 1 USB converter chip and no optocoupolers). In the event of a short on the board, it could send the high voltage back to the USB host, or to other places. This could be unsafe. I wouldn't use this board to switch anything above 30V and it would be really unsafe to switch AC mains voltages with this board.

They did use proper spacing for the relay traces however.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. I think I'm going for something safer, like this: 
https://sonoff.itead.cc/en/products/sonoff/sonoff-basic

Thank you all for your useful answers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the warning from "NCD" company is about, but I am pretty sure you shouldn't worry along your lines. The referenced USB board uses a regular relay with 5-V coil that takes only 71 mA to operate, so there should be no worries whatsoever about overloading of any USB port. The relay itself provides 1.5 kV isolation between its coil and power contacts, so there should be no concerns whatsoever about safety of operations controlling loads at 120-240V AC. However, you need to obey the relay's contact ratings, and 5A at 240V AC seems to be above the specifications the relay can handle for certain type of loads.